# Email form in Activity Composer does not render

Tags: lightning, email, lightning-experience, global-actions

I am having issues with Salesforce not rendering the form fields to send an email from both the activity composer as well as the global action. I am system admin profile so I have the send email permission. I am working from a Professional edition but I don't think that would affect the ability to send an email. Im not sure what setting I am missing to not show this email form.

Additional Confirmed Setup Options:
- Email Deliverability: All Email
- Enhanced Email: enabled
- Email quick action added to page layout

[image: Global Action New Email]

[image: activity composer from contact]

Answer (score 1):

The SendEmail action does not come with a default layout. You must add the email fields to the layout.

Setup > Search "Global Actions" > Email > Edit Layout